# K8s Test: no kind is registered for the type v1alpha1.JivaVolume in scheme

Tags: unit-testing, go, kubernetes

How can I register CRD in the k8s Test in golang?
I am creating fake client by:

```golang
k8sfake.NewSimpleClientset(
    &jivaPV1,
    &jv1,
)}},
```

I know I can register CRD by apply charts in the kubernetes, But not finding a good way to do such in golang.

I was using the `viaplha1.jivaVolume` interface, which was throwing the error that no kind is registered for the type `viaplha1.jivaVolume`. Here is a short code portion where I was creating a fake Persisten volume object of type jivaVolume.

```golang
var jv1 = v1alpha1.JivaVolume{
    TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{},
    ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
        Name:      "pvc-1",
        Namespace: "openebs",
        Labels:    map[string]string{"nodeID": "worker-node-1"},
    },
...
...
```

How can I register the kind in fakeClient? or How can I register CRD in fakeclient()?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the new controller API to scheme, Please Check this sample.

```
import (
        "context"
        "testing"
    
        cachev1alpha1 "github.com/some-operatorapi/pkg/apis/cache/v1alpha1"
        "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
        "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"
        "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client/fake"
    )
    
    func TestCachedController(t *testing.T) {
        ...
        // A Cached object with metadata and spec.
        cached := &cachev1alpha1.Cached{
            ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
                Name:      "memcached",
                Namespace: "memcached-operator",
                Labels: map[string]string{
                    "label-key": "label-value",
                },
            },
        }
    
        // Objects to track in the fake client.
        Objs := []runtime.Object{}
        Objs = append(Objs, cached)
        scheme := runtime.NewScheme()
        _ = cachev1alpha1.AddToScheme(scheme)
        cl:=  fake.NewClientBuilder().WithScheme(scheme).WithRuntimeObjects(Objs...).Build()
    
        // List Memcached objects filtering by labels
        opt := client.MatchingLabels(map[string]string{"label-key": "label-value"})
        memcachedList := &cachev1alpha1.MemcachedList{}
        err := cl.List(context.TODO(), memcachedList, opt)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("list memcached: (%v)", err)
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the CRD of your kind was not applied. K8s does not know what a `JivaVolume` kind is.